# Jquery LocationPicker plugin - inputBinding with external function

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-plugins

I want to change inputBindings values through external function.For example 
I have two inputs whose ids are "lati" and "longi" respectively.

When I change values of both inputs manually ,marker goes to the direction I typed.

But when I try to change their values through an external function by clicking an anchor,such as

```
function(){
$("#lati").val("41.014552663073545");
...
```

marker does go to the point I changed.
So,how to move marker through external function

Answer (score 0):

Instead of only changing the values of lati and longi (which probably does not affect the already declared marker), if you want to use the existing marker and change it's location only you probably want to first change the value then in your external function do something like the following:

```
var newLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lati, longi);
marker.setPosition(newLatLng);
```

Comment: My question is related to locationpicker plugin written for jquery,not java,Yet,thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

For those searching:

```
$('#map').locationpicker({
    location: {latitude: position.coords.latitude, longitude: position.coords.longitude},
});
```

where position.coords.latitude and position.coords.longitude are your latitude and longitude values which you can set and #map being the id of the div that was originally set up with .locationpicker()